# VSCode PHP - create function if not exist

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add a static method to my TestHelper class (see GIF). I want vscode to give me an option "create static method test in TestHelper". I used IntelliJ before and it was working there.

Does VSCode really don't have this feature? The only plugins I have installed is "PHP Intelliphense" and "Settings Sync"

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: what is the diagnostics message in the PROBLEMS Tab?

Comment: @rioV8, "{
 "resource": "....../ApiController.php",
 "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
 "code": "1013",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Undefined method 'test'.",
 "source": "intelephense",
 "startLineNumber": 455,
 "startColumn": 10,
 "endLineNumber": 455,
 "endColumn": 14
}"

Comment: I will adjust the extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) to handle this type of actions based on the content of the editor at the cursor, the class is not named in the diagnostics message

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of the 2 source files that have the problem, typing code from an animation is not easy

Comment: So VSCode isn't able to add new (not existing) methods by a shortcut likt CTRL + . ?

Comment: VSC is an editor not an IDE, VSC has no knowledge of any language, any language feature is implemented in an extension. Intellisense is done by a CodeCompletion provider in the language extension, 20-30 years back this was not even a feature in an IDE

Comment: So it isn't able?

Comment: not even the Premium (payed) version of `Intelephense` does it.

Comment: if you write an extension it can do it, with `My Code Actions` you can write the missing code actions from  the language server

Answer (score 1):

With the extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) v0.5.0 you can construct actions to add this method to the class if the file name equals the class name.

You can modify any property based on the captured fields, and add static text.

I have added a version that does not need a diagnostic (I don't have a PHP setup) but only uses the content of the editor at the cursor.

If you also need to create the file and the class have a look at the extension page for an example (that is for Angular).

Add this to your `settings.json`

```json
  "my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[php]": {
      "Add method {{diag:$1}} to {{atCursor:$1}}": {
        "diagnostics": ["Undefined method '(.*?)'."],
        "atCursor": "([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)::{{diag:$1}}",
        "text": "public function {{diag:$1}}() { }\n",
        "file": "{{atCursor:$1}}.php",
        "where": "afterLast",
        "insertFind": "class {{atCursor:$1}} {"
      },
      "No diag: Add method {{atCursor:$2}} to {{atCursor:$1}}": {
        "atCursor": "([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)::([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)",
        "text": "public function {{atCursor:$2}}() { }\n",
        "file": "{{atCursor:$1}}.php",
        "where": "afterLast",
        "insertFind": "class {{atCursor:$1}} {"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your extension at the weekend :)